# My cash value is suppose to go up every minute but its not. (Roblox Studio lua error)

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to re-edit the code over and over again but it still didn't work I've created the folder leader stats and when I play the game it shows that it's a part of the player. It says however that it isn't a valid member.

[image: The code that causes the error]

[image: The other code that causes another error]

[image: The error]
The other error says: Cash is not a valid member of Folder "Players.(players name).leaderstats"

Comment: Rather than sharing pictures of the code and errors, could you post the code as text so that we can easily work with it?

Comment: @Kylaaa here: you go local plays = game.Players.PlayerAdded

while wait(60) do
 plays.leaderstats.Cash.Value = plays.leaderstats.Cash.Value + 1
end

while true do
  wait(60)
  Player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = Player.leaderstats.Cash.Value + 1
  Player.Counter.Value = Player.Counter.Value + 1
 end

Comment: In the question and using code blocks...

Comment: Why in the first screenshot are you using "plays" variable but in the second screenshot your using the variable "Players".

Answer (score 3):

It's because `game.Players.PlayerAdded` is an event which you're assigning to a variable.

Try this for the PlayerAdded script (you will need that cash add function in this script):

```
local players = []

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(ply)
    table.insert(players, ply)
end)

while true do
    wait(60)
    for i, v in ipairs(players) do
       v:WaitForChild("leaderstats").Counter.Value += 1
    end
end
```

I've written this from my memory as I am away from a PC that can test this code so best of luck!

Comment: Well this without a playerRemoving function will start calling WaitForChild over nil all the time...

Answer (score 1):

```
while wait(60) do
    for i, v in ipairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        if v:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") then
            if v.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Counter") then
                v.leaderstats.Counter.Value += 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You always need to make sure what you're using exists. If you want to avoid errors, I prefer using FindFirstChild instead of WaitForChild to not get it into an infinite wait incase it somehow doesn't load.

Comment: Jeez, please fix your grammar mistakes :)

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you forgot to create the leaerstats folder. Here is a fixed code:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
   local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
   Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
   Leaderstats.Parent = player

   local Counter = Instance.new("IntValue")
   Counter.Name = "Counter"
   Counter.Parent = Leaderstats

   while true do
       task.wait(60)
       Counter.Value += 1
   end
end)
```

This will start counting time after player joins. If you want to increase counter value of all players at the same time, use this code:

```
local PlayersService = game:GetService("Players")

local Players = {}

PlayersService.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
   local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
   Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
   Leaderstats.Parent = player

   local Counter = Instance.new("IntValue")
   Counter.Name = "Counter"
   Counter.Parent = Leaderstats

   table.insert(Players, player)
end)

while true do
    task.wait(60)
    for _, player in ipairs(Players) do
      player.leaderstats.Counter.Value += 1
    end
end
```

You don't need to check if "Counter" or "leaderstats" exist as they are created before the player is being inserted into the table.

Comment: OP is't trying to increase the Counter value, they're trying to increase the Cash value.

Comment: So what is the problem? Just replace "Counter" with "Cash" lol

Comment: I just thought I'd point it out